# Unable to Print to Serial Monitor, Getting Error: "No core dump partition found!"

Tags: c++, esp32, platformio, serial-monitor

Working with an ESP32-s2, using platformIO with Visual Code Studio. I was running into some logic issues with my code (not necessary what, just background) and was attempting to use the serial monitor to debug. I added the necessary functionality to my program, made some adjustments to the baud rate and the PlatformIO config file to default to the correct COM port. After uploading the sketch I got this in the Serial Monitor.

```
ESP-ROM:esp32s2-rc4-20191025
Build:Oct 25 2019
rst:0x1 (POWERON),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3ffe6100,len:0x1684
load:0x4004c000,len:0x1018
load:0x40050000,len:0x2f04
entry 0x4004c354
␛[0;32mI (21) boot: ESP-IDF v4.4.1-405-g6c5fb29c2c 2nd stage bootloader␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (21) boot: compile time 04:22:07␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (22) boot: chip revision: 0␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (25) qio_mode: Enabling default flash chip QIO␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (31) boot.esp32s2: SPI Speed      : 80MHz␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (35) boot.esp32s2: SPI Mode       : QIO␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (40) boot.esp32s2: SPI Flash Size : 4MB␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (45) boot: Enabling RNG early entropy source...␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (50) boot: Partition Table:␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (54) boot: ## Label            Usage          Type ST Offset   Length␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (61) boot:  0 nvs              WiFi data        01 02 00009000 00005000␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (69) boot:  1 otadata          OTA data         01 00 0000e000 00002000␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (76) boot:  2 ota_0            OTA app          00 10 00010000 00160000␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (83) boot:  3 ota_1            OTA app          00 11 00170000 00160000␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (91) boot:  4 uf2              factory app      00 00 002d0000 00040000␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (98) boot:  5 ffat             Unknown data     01 81 00310000 000f0000␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (106) boot: End of partition table␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (610) esp_image: segment 0: paddr=00010020 vaddr=3f000020 size=0b458h ( 46168) map␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (618) esp_image: segment 1: paddr=0001b480 vaddr=3ffbedb0 size=02fech ( 12268) load␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (621) esp_image: segment 2: paddr=0001e474 vaddr=40024000 size=01ba4h (  7076) load␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (626) esp_image: segment 3: paddr=00020020 vaddr=40080020 size=234ech (144620) map␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (657) esp_image: segment 4: paddr=00043514 vaddr=40025ba4 size=0920ch ( 37388) load␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (666) esp_image: segment 5: paddr=0004c728 vaddr=50000000 size=00010h (    16) load␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (672) boot: Loaded app from partition at offset 0x10000␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (672) boot: Disabling RNG early entropy source...␛[0m
E (696) esp_core_dump_flash: No core dump partition found!
E (696) esp_core_dump_flash: No core dump partition found!
```

I received this error twice, once with my actual code and the second with the following code below. I adjusted the baud rate, restarted VSC and tried again thinking something in configuration was hanging me up. Still nothing. The only thing that's different is for the test code, I'm getting an error message inside VSC that says it can't find "Serial" library. So I had to include it, which is strange since I didn't have to with my actual code I'm guessing it was included through another library, but eh?

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("hello");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Regardless, when running my actual code everything uploads fine with no issues and I have feedback from my LCD screen. Touch is working, the logic for the touch is working. It's just this error message and I'm not getting some of the lines I was expecting inside of the serial monitor in order to debug some logic issues.

Comment: I tried again using Arduino IDE and I got the same message. Going to try and reflash firmware to the ESP32 and see that resolves it, though I think that is done when you upload the sketch. But worth a shot I guess.

Comment: Still no luck, tried reflashing the binaries from Espressif, and even downloaded MicroPython and tried recompiling from Arduino again to overwrite the binaries. No luck. It appears to still function but I have no Serial Monitor support. I suspect that this is not the correct board and that is what is casuing the problem. Going back to my original ESP 32 WROVER

Comment: I went back to my ESP32 and gave up. There’s nothing wrong with the one I was using it’s just not capable of running inside the serial monitor for some reason. I never tested it before. Could be that there is no support for this board yet, but I’m just speculating.

Comment: I have the ESP32s3. I begun to get this error message (on startup) once I activated some debug features. I was not able to remove it since then. What you can do is to create a dump partition: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/core_dump.html#save-core-dump-to-flash

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the ESP tells you did not provide a section in the partition so that it can handle core dump for future analysis.

When something goes wrong, the ESP will record the state of the software (aka the core dump) as it were. Then you can take you esp and read the dump on your PC whenever you want to analyse what was wrong.

To remove the notice, you have to add the section in your partition file. Here is mine for example (suitable for 16MB flash version):

pepsr_16MB_84KBnvs.csv

```
# Name,     Type,   SubType, Offset,    Size,   Flags # 20KB NVS October 4th 2022 by Sdl
# Added 64K core dump section
nvs,        data,   nvs,    0x9000,     0x5000
otadata,    data,   ota,    0xE000,     0x2000
app0,       app,    ota_0,  0x10000,    0x2A0000
app1,       app,    ota_1,  0x2B0000,   0x2A0000
ffat,       data,   fat,    0x550000,   0x2A0000
coredump,   data,   coredump,,          64K
```

See the last line that reserves 64KB (0x100000) of space for the ESP to dump the data into.

@see [ESP core dump doc](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/core_dump.html#save-core-dump-to-flash) for more information